# LINQ to SQL Sequence contains more than one element

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am getting an error when trying to delete a record from the database.

Here is my current deletion code:

```
Dim BAToRemove = From i In uDC.BookAuthors _
                       Where i.authorID = intAuthorID _
                       And i.bookID = intBookID _
                       And i.main = "N" _
                       Select i Take (1) Distinct

        If BAToRemove.Any Then
            Dim ba As BookAuthor = BAToRemove.First
            uDC.BookAuthors.DeleteOnSubmit(ba)

            Dim cs As ChangeSet = uDC.GetChangeSet

            uDC.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict)

            If cs.Deletes.Count = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
```

This is the code after fiddling to try and get it to work. Even without the .First and Take(1) distinct, the query definitely only returns a single result. I have used BAToRemove.Count and also manually checked the table and there is only one matching row.

Both BookID and AuthorID are primary keys.

I have also tried just using BAToRemove.First straight in the DeleteOnSubmit.

I have also tried copying all of the elements of the returned object to a new object, then attaching and deleting but I get the error that the element already exists (which it does).

All of the other posts I have founded regarding this problem always seems to turn out to be the fault of using SingleOrDefault, which I am not using, so I'm stumped on this one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try calling `DeleteAllOnSubmit(ba)` and check what gets executed in SQL server profiler, this should give you a heads up on whats going wrong.

Comment: Changing to DeleteAllOnSubmit(ba) gives the following design time error:
Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in method 'Public Sub DeleteAllOnSubmit(Of TSubEntity As TEntity)(entities As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TSubEntity))' cannot be inferred from these arguments.

If I use DeleteAllOnSubmit(BAToRemove.First) then it seems to work fine with no errors. That's really annoying because I swear I tried that before.
 When trying so many solutions to an error, its sometimes hard to remember which ones you have tried!

Comment: I had the same problem and found the reason in my case - [see my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17150062/463828).